# Does unpacking textures give better performance in viewport and render?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, packed-data, packing

I've gotten used to automatically packing my textures into the blend file, but I wonder if that can make my viewport perfomance slower, (Rendering and not rendering in viewport)

Should I unpack for better experience or it doesnt make a difference ?

Comment: i recommend reading this: https://artisticrender.com/blender-pack-external-files-how-why-when/

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I doubt it will make any difference as in both cases the image is loaded in the RAM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the file size of the blend file influence the render performance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63488/does-the-file-size-of-the-blend-file-influence-the-render-performance)

Comment: Loading packed images from inside a blend file is generally slower than reading the same image file directly saved in the file system, so whenever the image is read it may take longer, but after loading into memory it should make no difference

Answer (score 1):

Judging from my own experience as well as the [article](https://artisticrender.com/blender-pack-external-files-how-why-when/) linked by Harry McKenzie, no, packing files does not affect render performance. The file still ends up loaded into the RAM in generally the same way. The blend file will be larger, however.